# Creating QGIS multi-layer Topo Map of Lorraine Region of France?

Tags: qgis, topography, france

I have a project I'm working on where I need a QGIS multi-layer Topo Map go the Lorraine Region of France between Metz and Nancy as a starting point, but I don't know where to start.  What I need is a georefenced map so that I can utilize the roads, raliroads and river layers as well as the elevation contour lines.

I'm a newbie, so this is a lot to learn.

Comment: Not sure what 'multi-layer topo map' means. Topo would normally be its own layer, as would any other features - roads, rail, rivers, etc. Are you simply looking for data to start with? You mention a georeferenced map; would that be a raster map so you can digitize the features yourself? Or are you looking for vector base data?

Comment: A good starting point is installing QGIS. After that you need to acquire data of some sort... local government can be a good source; there is openlayers (there's a plugin for that) which is also good... it just depends on the scale and the accuracy requirement (and how forthcoming your government is). You could get old maps from a library and georeference them yourself... the possibilities are nearly endless! Considering you're using QGIS I'd say you're not about to commission a LiDAR/aerial photography project. Can you give more information on what this is for?